# How do FE solvers solve the case of panel buckling under pure shear?

Tags: finite-element-method, shear, buckling, stiffness

How do FE solvers solve the case of panel buckling under pure shear?
The main problem is that global matrix of initial stess is singular in that case. One method is to apply some forces that shear is not so pure. But I think there should be some alternatives. So what do you think?